# change a label and add a value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I want to change a label that is on my design I have linked them up and when i use this code it dosn't change
This is in H

```
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    NSInteger fred;
```

This is in M

```
fred = fred+1;
    label.text = @"Level : " +fred;
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
label.text = @"Level : " +fred;
```

use

```
 label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level : %d" ,fred];
```